# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in aside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I'm using ng-strap's modal, alert, and aside. They are all working fine by themselves, but when I try to put an alert or modal inside an aside, it gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/vLbDAarzpbT3qk0aNw12?p=preview

I used the exact same code (copied & pasted) for the modal/alert buttons in and outside of the aside.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-animation="am-fade-and-scale" data-placement="center" bs-modal="myModal">Modal!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-placement="top" data-container="body" data-duration="3" bs-alert="errorAlert">Alert!</button>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with `angular-strap`. Have you tried posting an issue on github ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem yes, I did this morning. Nobody has replied yet. https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="aside-body">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-animation="am-fade-and-scale" data-placement="center" ng-click="$isShown = false" bs-modal="myModal">Modal!</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-placement="top" data-container="body" data-duration="3" ng-click="$isShown = false" bs-alert="errorAlert">Alert!</button>
</div>
```

- The ng-strap library sets a variable $isShown in the scope to indicate whether the modal is currently opening.
- When you click "Click to open aside", it sets that variable to true. When you click the "Modal" button inside the aside, it checks that variable, see that it's opening (but actually it's the other modal) so it toggles the modal to close. But the modal for "Modal" button is not actually shown yet, causing the error
- Not sure what's the proper way to fix this, because I haven't used this library before. One "hack" to make the modal to work is to manually set $isShown variable to false when you click "Modal" button inside aside, like the code above: ng-click="$isShown = false"
- Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/qVy1Gol7RWGnsNUCMBWm?p=preview